# Confusion on how to set parameter grid when comparing multiple pipeline steps in a single GridSearchCV run

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm trying to set up a comparison of different pipeline steps within a single GridSearchCV run. The only example I have to go by is this one on scikit-learn, couldn't find any additional information through a web search.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/plot_compare_reduction.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-plot-compare-reduction-py

I have a few questions regarding this example:

```
pipe = Pipeline([
    ('reduce_dim', PCA()),
    ('classify', LinearSVC())
])

N_FEATURES_OPTIONS = [2, 4, 8]
C_OPTIONS = [1, 10, 100, 1000]
param_grid = [
    {
        'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()],
        'reduce_dim__n_components': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
    {
        'reduce_dim': [SelectKBest(chi2)],
        'reduce_dim__k': N_FEATURES_OPTIONS,
        'classify__C': C_OPTIONS
    },
]
```

1. Here they are swapping in different reduce_dim pipeline steps by passing a list.  How do you have more fine-grain control of the parameter grid if more than one function in the list have the same parameter name but you want to specify one?  In the example reduce_dim__n_components is a parameter for PCA() and NMF(), in general when specifying a list of steps to swap in how do you set up the parameter grid to specify parameters for a particular function in the list?  Or do you write it a different way?
2. Looking at the initial Pipeline() and steps declaration at the top does scikit-learn run that? So is it running three comparisons or is the initial declaration a placeholder and it is running two?

Answer (score 2):

1. I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking, but perhaps you mean "How can I specify 'classify_C' only once despite varying the dimensionality reduction method?" One answer to that is [`searchgrid`](http://searchgrid.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) which allows you to set parameters local to each estimator in a pipeline.
2. No it does not do anything with the initial parameters until they are modified by the parameter grid. So the initial declaration is effectively a placeholder.

Comment: For 1. what I mean is, what if for example for 'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()] I want to search over a different n_components for PCA and different n_components for NMF?  I know this is a bad example, but in general when you are passing a list of pipeline steps as a parameter, how do you specify in the parameter grid for those steps specific parameters to search for each function?

Comment: You can use `reduce_dim__n_components` for both, so a grid like `{'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7), NMF()], 'reduce_dim__n_components': [1,2,3]}` should work. But searchgrid's way of specifying it may be more intuitive.

Comment: Sorry I'm not coming across, my thread question is: how do I specify for each function in the reduce_dim list *individually*, such that I specify an n_components search list for PCA only, and another and different n_components search list for NMF only.  I know PCA and NMF are not a great example to want individual settings, but I want to know in general how it's done for this general gridsearchcv case when you are passing in pipeline functions as a parameter.

Comment: You need a separate dict for each `reduce_dim`, then, e.g. `{'reduce_dim': [PCA(iterated_power=7)], 'reduce_dim__n_components': [1,2,3]}, {'reduce_dim': [NMF()], 'reduce_dim__n_components': [4,5,6]}`. Again searchgrid makes this clearer, I hope.